# seaborn figure saving problem.how can i solve it?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

[image: here is my data format]

And here is my code,

> ```
> ax = sns.lineplot(x="time", y="Aerosol_Optical_Depth_Land_Ocean", data=df)
>
> ax.tick_params(rotation=45)
> fig = ax.get_figure()
> fig.savefig("aod_timeSeries.png") 
> plt.show()
> ```

when I run this code it saves the figure.it cuts the x-label.
[image: saved picture]

But when I download the figure it looks perfect.[image: downloaded picture]
but I wanted to save this with code.
I also tried this way

> plt.savefig("aod_timeSeries.png")

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tight_layout` function

```py
ax = sns.lineplot(x="time", y="Aerosol_Optical_Depth_Land_Ocean", data=df)
ax.tick_params(rotation=45)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("a.jpg")
```